# SQL - Group by to get sum but also return a row if the sum is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
ID BuyOrSell Total
4    B         10
4    B         11
4    S         13
4    S         29
8    B         20
9    S         23
```

What I am trying to do is to have sum of B and S columns for each ID and if there is not a B or S for an ID have a row with 0, so expected output would be

```
ID BuyOrSell Total
4    B         21
4    S         42
8    B         20
8    S          0
9    S         23
9    B          0
```

I have tried this and it is kind of doing what I am after but not exactly:

```
DECLARE @Temp Table (ID int, BuyOrSell VARCHAR(1), charge Decimal)
INSERT INTO @Temp 
SELECT 4, 'B', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B', 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S', 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'S', 29 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'B', 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'S', 23 

;With Results AS
(
SELECT ID,
       BuyOrSell,
       SUM(charge) AS TOTAL
FROM @Temp 
Group by ID, BuyOrSell
)
Select t.*,max(
                case when BuyOrSell = 'B' then 'Bfound' 
                end) over (partition by ID) as ref
            ,max(
                case when BuyOrSell = 'S' then 'Sfound' 
                end) over (partition by ID) as ref
FROM Results t;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE(ID, BuyOrSell) AS(
    SELECT 
        ID, T.BuyOrSell 
    FROM @Temp
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'S'
    )T(BuyOrSell)
    GROUP BY ID, T.BuyOrSell
)
SELECT
    C.ID,
    C.BuyOrSell,
    Total = ISNULL(SUM(T.charge), 0)
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN @Temp T
    ON T.ID = C.ID
    AND T.BuyOrSell = C.BuyOrSell
GROUP BY C.ID, C.BuyOrSell
ORDER BY C.ID, C.BuyOrSell
```

Answer (score 0):

@03Usr, despite that your question has been answered, please try this:

```
         SELECT two.ID,
                two.BuyOrSell,
                ISNULL (one.Total, 0) Total
           FROM
        (SELECT ID,
                BuyOrSell,
                SUM (Total) Total
           FROM @Temp
       GROUP BY ID, BuyOrSell) one
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT ID,
                BuyOrSell
           FROM @Temp
       GROUP BY ID,
                BuyOrSell) two
             ON one.ID = two.ID
            AND one.BuyOrSell = two.BuyOrSell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with tricky join:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
       v.l as BuyOrSell, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.BuyOrSell = v.l THEN t1.charge ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM @Temp t1
JOIN (VALUES('B'),('S')) v(l) 
  ON t1.BuyOrSell = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Temp t2 
                                     WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.BuyOrSell <> t1.BuyOrSell) 
                         THEN v.l ELSE t1.BuyOrSell END
GROUP BY t1.ID, v.l
ORDER BY t1.ID, v.l
```

Output:

```
ID  l   Total
4   B   21
4   S   42
8   B   20
8   S   0
9   B   0
9   S   23
```